# Unable to query existing Hive installation from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Background:

I have a separate Hive installation which is running in embedded mode. The contents of hive-site.xml are as below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp</value>
    <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Whether or not to allow dynamic partitions in DML/DDL.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
    <value>strict</value>
    </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.mode.local.auto</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>Let Hive determine whether to run in local mode automatically</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>mine</value>
    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>APP</value>
    <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

When I run below queries directly on Hive, it works as expected. A directory with the given tablename is created in hdfs under **hive.metastore.warehouse.dir** and data is stored into it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employeedetails (eid int, name String,salary String, destination String)
COMMENT 'Employee details'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/rahul/Desktop/inputfiles/sample.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employeedetails;


SELECT * FROM employeedetails;
```

**Issue 1**

Now, when I access it from Spark-shell, it is not able to find the table.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

scala> val hiveCtx = new HiveContext(sc)
hiveCtx: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@2e667e95

scala> val rows = hiveCtx.sql("select eid, name, salary, destination from employeedetails")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: employeedetails; line 1 pos 43
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:459)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:478)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:463)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)
```

**Issue 2**

When I tried executing the above queries from Spark-shell, it ran into exception as below. I think it looks for the path at local machine.

```
scala> val rows = hiveCtx.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employeedetails (eid int, name String,salary String, destination String) COMMENT 'Employee details' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'STORED AS TEXTFILE")

17/07/01 18:15:57 WARN metastore.HiveMetaStore: Location: file:/user/hive/warehouse/employeedetails specified for non-external table:employeedetails
17/07/01 18:15:57 ERROR metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/employeedetails is not a directory or unable to create one)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1394)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1449)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.create_table_with_environment_context(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2050)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:669)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:657)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:156)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.createTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:714)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:425)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:425)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:425)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.createTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:424)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:191)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:191)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:191)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateTableCommand.run(tables.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:699)
at $line16.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:27)
at $line16.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:32)
at $line16.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:34)
at $line16.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:36)
at $line16.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:38)
at $line16.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:40)
at $line16.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
at $line16.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:44)
at $line16.$read.<init>(<console>:46)
at $line16.$read$.<init>(<console>:50)
at $line16.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
at $line16.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
at $line16.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
at $line16.$eval.$print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/employeedetails is not a directory or unable to create one);
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:98)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:191)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateTableCommand.run(tables.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:185)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:699)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/employeedetails is not a directory or unable to create one)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:720)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:425)

  ... 66 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: file:/user/hive/warehouse/employeedetails is not a directory or unable to create one
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1394)
```

---

Note:-

1. I have copied the **hive-site.xml** from hive installation to **/spark/conf/**
2. I also tried changing the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir parameter as **hdfs://localhost:9000/** just to point to HDFS but no benefit.
   **hdfs://localhost:9000** is set to **fs.defaultFS** in my **hadoop core-site.xml**.

I googled as well but didn't get proper solution. Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Finally I managed to get over the issue. The problem was with the metastore_db . Spark was picking up the different location for the metastore_db and not the one created when queried using hive.